# Array of elements by class - TypeError: $.id is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I'm trying to create an array from the elements of a div that all share a class.

The div's ID is `settingsMenu` and all of the elements I need to store in the array share a `menuOption` class.
The JQuery attempt is as follows:

```
var options = $.id('settingsMenu').getElementsByClassName('menuOption');
```

When I execute the function with this statement inside, the error I get is:

> "Uncaught TypeError: $.id is not a
>   function"

The `$.id` seems to be problematic, am I using it wrong?

Dummy HTML:

```
<div id="settingsMenu">
    <input type="text" class="menuOption" />
    <input type="checkbox" class="menuOption" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not totally sure I'd take this approach, nor have I seen this method for selecting an element by ID. Why not just nest the selector with the following?

```
var options = $('#settingsMenu .menuOption');
```

[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/s89py267/) - demo

---

Be sure to check out the [jQuery ID Selector (“#id”) docs](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) as well as [selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) in general

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use jQuery, then you don't need to use the pure Javascript functions like [`getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) as [jQuery provides a very easy to use syntax](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) for accessing DOM elements.

You could refactor your code as follows :

```
// This will retrieve all elements with the class "menuOption" below an element 
// with ID "settingsMenu"
var options = $('#settingsMenu .menuOption');
```